# What could be the possible reason behind huge difference between response time of a page in chrome and same in chromium?

Tags: chromium, loadrunner, truclient

I have me testing a application using Loadrunner TruClient using browser Chromium, which gives me response time of a page as 50 seconds on an average.
But when i see the timings for the same page in Chrome, it is not more than 10 seconds on an average.
I have tried checking developer tool for both, but couldn't figure the difference.
Can anyone help me figure out the possible cause behind this?
Thanks

Comment: in this to an objective measure in both, such s domComplete, domInteractive, etc....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please tell me the detail about where did you get the response time of a page as 50 seconds? Is is it from the browser devtool or TruClient transaction time? As @Alex said, TruClient is using end event to statistic the reponse time. TruClient have injected its own logic to static the network traffic information. It is not as same as native Chrome devtool. It will exclude the unnecessary waiting time in the final report.

Best regards,
Edwin

Answer (score 0):

TruClient step uses End Event to determine when the step ends. End event impacts how long a step takes. [Understanding end events](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/tc/en/2020/Content/TruClient/procedures/understanding_end_events.htm) describes all end events. [View or edit the step structure](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/tc/en/2020/Content/TruClient/_tc_lp_step_structure.htm#mt-item-1) describes how to manually set step end event. Try different step end events, see if it works for you.